# Child surveillance and monitoring of Internet use

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, skype, parental-control, children

The child of a friend of mine was in contact with a pedophile/pervert on the Internet. I provide support for the PC of my friend and he asked me for help.

The contact was on a game forum and in Skype.

What software approach (Windows 7) could be used to prevent this?

---

P.S. #1 The kid was instructed hundreds of times to avoid contact with strangers. But kids are not adults and sometimes are cheated by experienced people.

P.S. #2 The kid will be instructed more by his parents. I (and you) cannot contribute more for this. So please be constructive with software measures that could prevent this or allow parents to monitor the child's activity.

Comment: Please make sure you contact the game forum, and get this guy banned if you haven't done so already.

Comment: we are starting contact with police. The dad wants to force the law and do what we can to protect other kids. Just banning the pervert can't stop him from making new registration.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from experience with quite a few web blocking systems, one of the best I've seen is called K9 Web Protection. It has a quite a few features that make this program awesome.

1. Backed by Blue Coat Systems, an enterprise level security company.
2. Always up to date web categorizing. If you want to block games forums, questionable websites, etc. K9 is always up to date with websites and will block new ones if there in the blocking list.
3. Produce reports showing activity to categories of websites
4. Can't get rid of it - even if your an admin* on the PC. You can't uninstall it without authentication from a parent who set it up.
5. Time restrictions
6. Provides it's own search engine, up to you if you want to enforce its use
7. Free for home use

> Free, enterprise-class security software designed for home computers
> Malware attacks are increasing exponentially every day. In fact,
> August 2009 set a record with more than 56,000 documented phishing
> attacks. To protect your home computer from online threats of all
> kinds, you need a robust security solution that’s updated in real
> time.
>
> With Blue Coat K9 Web Protection, you don’t have to wait for the
> latest security patch or upgrade, which can leave your computer
> vulnerable to new and evolving Web threats. K9 delivers the
> comprehensive protection you need automatically. With K9, you get the
> same advanced Web filtering technology used by enterprise and
> government institutions worldwide — all with a user-friendly interface
> that allows you to control Internet use in your home.
>
> [image: Screenshot]

<sup>*It is ***extremely hard* to remove** and hypothetically if it did, you would know</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I use Qustodio for my boys at home.   It blocks apps that you do not want them to use, you can set time allowances, block questionable content etc.  I get a daily report via email of the previous days activity and if they violate any rules I setup I get an immediate notification from them.  All this is using their free version too (which lets you set it up on one windows account).  The program files can be hidden during install and if you ever try to uninstall it requires your Qustodio account password.

https://www.qustodio.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

NoTrack but you have to make a dns server which you could host on a pi. NoTrack allows for domain blocking at the dns level and you can see what the users have been on.